# when i use nvim, <C-`> keymapping does not working in tmux

Tags: tmux, neovim, telescope

i have been used <kbd>Ctrl-`</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-=</kbd> keymapping for telescope.nvim and work fine.
but when i use <kbd>Ctrl-`</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-=</kbd> keymapping in tmux, it does not working and get error

- `E20: mark not set vim`
- `E21: cannot make changes`

what is wrong with me? other keymappings work fine in tmux. please help me

environment: mac + iterm2 + zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most terminal apps can only recognize the following ctrl chars:

- <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> .. <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-@</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-_</kbd>

and they cannot tell the difference between, for example, <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctr-[</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>, ... (more details [here](https://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/)).

Nvim uses [libtermkey](https://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/) which can recognize more ctrl sequences but for tmux, <kbd>Ctrl-`</kbd> is the same as <kbd>`</kbd> so tmux just forwards <kbd>`</kbd> to nvim. And for <kbd>Ctrl-=</kbd>, nvim would receive <kbd>=</kbd>.

As a workaround you need to use other keybingings which both nvim and tmux can recognize.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I need to change the key :)